# Confusion over 得，唔得 + verb

Tags: cantonese, verbs, negation

I am confused about how to construct (and understand) phrases that involve: 得 and its negative 唔得 with a verb.

Specifically, what is the difference between 唔得買，冇買得。

A corresponding confusion would be how to say the following in cantonese: wasn’t able to buy, don’t buy. Are there other patterns i should know?

Please suggest a definitive rule for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

買 = buy

買[**得**] = [**can**] buy (allowed to buy)

[**唔**]買[**得**] = [**can't**] buy (not allowed to buy)

[**冇得**]買 = [**not available**] to buy

- *冇買得 is ungrammatical*

食 = eat

食[**得**] = [**can**] eat (allowed to eat)

[**唔**]食[**得**] = [**can't**] eat (not allowed to eat)

[**冇得**]食 = [**not available**] to eat

For "don't" it is "唔好"

Example:

**唔好**買貴嘢 = **don't** buy expensive stuff

**唔好**食太多鹽 = **don't** eat too much salt

Notice:

- [唔好][食] = [don't][eat]
- [唔][好食] = [not] [tasting good]